# how to only change the content with every navigation while keeping the user objects constant

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary, touchxml, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i have used a tutorial online which uses touchXML and parsed a particular website so that it provides me all the elements with their values

```
// Convert the supplied URL string into a usable URL object

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: blogAddress];

// Create a new rssParser object based on the TouchXML "CXMLDocument" class, this is the
// object that actually grabs and processes the RSS data

    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

// Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser

    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

// Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed

    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];

// Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data

 for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

    // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries

 NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Create a counter variable as type "int"

 int counter;

    // Loop through the children of the current  node
    for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

        // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
        [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];

    }

    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
    [blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];
```

now since i have all the data in blogEntries mutableDictionary,i have a label object and 2 bar button item on top saying back & next
**what i actually want to do is**

**1)on clicking next use the same label object and load the next data from the blogEntries mutableDictionary**

**2)on clicking back use the same label object and load the previous data from the blogEntries mutableDictionary**

if suppose anyone has any other idea apart from loading new content without using the bar button items,you're welcome
my project basically deals with rss feeds,so all i want to do is just navigate the next news by clicking next or using swipegesture..thanks